# updating bot embed - discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I want the bot to update the embed every 4 seconds and this is my code:

```js
if (cmd === 'fivemst') {
  function updateEmbed() {
    sys.probe('cfx.re', async (isAlive) => {
      if (isAlive) {
        embed = new MessageEmbed().setAuthor(
          'FiveM System Status -  ',
          'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1041091660316160032/1053741836725915818/82d62076a21ee0f408aa344403324efb5eb669cd.png',
        ).setDescription(`
         ✅

      **All Systems Operational**
      `);
      } else {
        embed = new MessageEmbed().setAuthor(
          'FiveM System Status - ',
          'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1041091660316160032/1053741836725915818/82d62076a21ee0f408aa344403324efb5eb669cd.png',
        ).setDescription(`
         ❎

      **Partial System Outage**
      `);
      }
      message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] }).then((message) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          message.edit({ embeds: [embed] });
        });
      }, 4000);
    });
  }
  setInterval(updateEmbed, 4000);
}
```

I tried this code but the bot is sending a new embed and not updating the last embed sent.

Comment: You're telling your bot to send a new message in your `updateEmbed`. `message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })` will send a new one every four seconds.

Comment: what should i do to edit the bot message and update it

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should proceed. Storing the last sent message in a variable and use it to update the content.

```js
if (cmd === 'fivemst') {
    let message = null;
    function updateMessageWithNewEmbed() {
        sys.probe('cfx.re', async (isAlive) => {
            if (isAlive) {
                embed = new MessageEmbed().setAuthor(
                    'FiveM System Status -  ',
                    'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1041091660316160032/1053741836725915818/82d62076a21ee0f408aa344403324efb5eb669cd.png',
                ).setDescription(`
                    ✅

                **All Systems Operational**
                `);
            } else {
                embed = new MessageEmbed().setAuthor(
                    'FiveM System Status - ',
                    'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1041091660316160032/1053741836725915818/82d62076a21ee0f408aa344403324efb5eb669cd.png',
                ).setDescription(`
                    ❎

                **Partial System Outage**
                `);
            }
            if (message) message.edit({
                embeds: [embed]
            });
            else {
                message = await message.channel.send({
                    embeds: [embed]
                });
            }
        });
    }
    setInterval(() => updateMessageWithNewEmbed(), 4000);
}
```

Comment: if it works feel free to mark the answer as correct!

Comment: yes it worked but its giving me always Partial System Outage and on website all system is working

Comment: ah all right, please open a new question for that issue

Comment: you can help me on this question because i cant submit a new question i should wait 2 days